# Can we set default date formatting for __toString() method of date?

Tags: php, datetime

For example I have a date:

```
$date = mktime();
```

And in out project I have many palces were we used

```
echo $date
```

Can we change formatting of date in this case? How can we make it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `__toString` magic method can only be declared for classes/objects. Since `mktime` returns an integer, you can't overload it.

There is the [DateTime](http://php.net/DateTime) class since PHP 5.2. Technically, you can create your own `MyDateTime` that extends the built-in one (or simply create your own DateTime class) and overload `__toString` there, to represent whatever default date/time string you want.

If you want to stick with `mktime` (which by way, returns the same as `time` when no arguments are passed to it), you can use either `date` or `stftime`:

```
$dateTime = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $time);
$dateTime = strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S', $time);
```

Answer (score 2):

You could wrap PHP date processing in your own custom class to achieve a custom `__toString()` value:

```
class MyDate
{
    private $date;
    private $format = 'r';

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->date = mktime();
    }

    public function setFormat($format)
    {
        $this->format = $format;
    }

    public function __toString()
    {
        return date($this->format, $this->date);
    }
}
```

You could then call this as the following:

```
$date = new MyDate();
echo $date; // "Fri, 12 Nov 2010 17:21:28 +0100"
$date->setFormat('d/m/Y');
echo $date; // "12/11/2010"
```

If you wanted to do this with custom dates, you would have to write the functionality to pass them from the constructor to the `mktime` call. This shouldn't be difficult.

Answer (score 0):

PHP has a built-in function to do this:

http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.format.php

Formatting symbols are here:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php

Answer (score 0):

Check out the [date](http://php.net/date) function in PHP. Example #3 and #4 scale well to what you are asking.

Answer (score 0):

Building on Evan's response: even if you don't have PHP 5.2.0 or greater, the [date()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) function will format the time.